# Next.JS Image returns image src as object

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, src

I have a page and a component below,
and I want to pass src as props for Image.

But it shows an error saying 'Cannot find module'.

How can I pass a image src?

```
import image from '../public/image/state=user=default.svg'

  const formInputs = [
    {
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: t.LOGIN_ADDRESS,
      src: test,
      name: 'email',
    },
    {
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: t.LOGIN_PASSWORD,
      src: test,
      name: 'password',
    },
  ];

<FormikForm fields={formInputs} />
```

**I got a data like below as src props.**

height: 20

src: "/_next/static/media/state=user=default.b726de9c.svg"

width: 20

```
export const FormikForm = ({ fields }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {fields &&
        fields.map((field) => (
          <div className="mb-4" key={field.name}>
              <label htmlFor={field.name} className="text-xs">
                {field.label}
                          <Field
        name={field.name}
        type={field.type}
        placeholder={
          <Image src={require(field.src.src)} width={12} height={12} alt={field.name} />
        }
      />
              </label>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is the `image` variable being used in your code? You import it but don't reference it anywhere. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

If you have static files in your public folder you want to use the `src` of, just use the value directly:

```
src: '/image/state=user=default.svg'
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Comment: I edited like <Image src={src} width={12} height={12} alt={name} />, but it doesn't work. it just shows [object Object].

Comment: Please try the way I mentioned by just setting it to '/image/state=user=default.svg' directlky and see if it shows in the Image. That's how the documentation recommends it, don't import it as an object and use the object field (as you can see it's a different/internal url)